# logic for returning a substring with highest number of vowel

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

You are given with a string and length of a substring .You are required to determine the substring with highest number of vowels .The substring can be a combination of vowel and consonant but it should have the highest number of vowels.

example:

input
`string= azerdii`
length of substring=5

`substrings= azerd,zerdi,erdii`

**erdii** has highest number of vowels so output should be **erdii**

Kindly help me with the code in Python3

Comment: you should share what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
#fetch all substrings
string_is = 'azerdii'
sub = 5
length = len(string_is)
sub_ar = [string_is[i:j+1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i,length)]
#print(sub_ar)

#fetch substrings of a length = 5
sub_ar_is = []
for each in sub_ar:
  if len(each) == 5:
    sub_ar_is.append(each)
print(sub_ar_is)
data_dict = {}
data = ['a','e','i','o','u']
for each in sub_ar_is:
  count = 0
  for each_is in data:
    count = count + each.count(each_is)
  data_dict.update({each:count})

print(data_dict)
print("Substring is: ", max(data_dict, key=data_dict.get))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def findSubstring(s, k):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    return_output = ["Not found!"]
    max_countt = 0
    
    # loop size such that index don't gets out of range
    length = len(s)-k+1
    for i in range(length):  

        # temporary storage of vowel count
        sum_count = 0  

        # getting string of desire size
        output = s[i:i+k]

        # count of vowels in the string
        for vowel in vowels:
            sum_count += output.count(vowel) 

        # if vowels in the string is greater than string having max vowels
        # replace the max vowel string and number of max vowel count
        if max_countt < sum_count:
            return_output = output
            max_countt = sum_count
    
    # return output
    return "".join(return_output)

print(findSubstring("azerdii", 5))
```